# Mocked method inside dict

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I have a class

```
class A(object):
    def method_1(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
    def method_2(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

In test i want mock some of methods, i do it so

```
from mock import patch

@patch('path.to.A.method_1')
class TestA(self, *args):
    ...
```

When test is working, i call A.__dict__ and get method_1 as property

```
'method_1', <MagicMock id='4424568720'>
```

How can i exclude mocked method from __dict__?

Comment: When you mock any class/function, the object that you access in your tests is not the original object. Hence the `__dict__` would contain details of the updated object. Could you add a few more details on why you are using the `__dict__` method in the tests?

Comment: @JRajan I want to calculate hash of all available properties. Mocking method_1 is need, cause it use API. So i need exlude this property on test script and calculate md5.

Comment: I would loop through the keys and exclude the ones which evaluate True for `isinstance(value, MagicMock)`.